# How can I select two tables in MySQL but only select one column from the 2nd table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one table is for users and stores everything about the user, but more importantly a users profile image stored as a file location. The second table is an images table, where images location and information is stored, such as title and description.

I need to link the profile image to the user who uploaded the photo. The users table has a user_id and profile_image, and the images table has just a user_id.

How can I select all of the images table and just the profile image in one query? Is this even possible?

**Edit**
I have been looking at joins but can't seem to figure it out. The tables look like this:

```
IMAGES                             USERS
id                                 user_id
user_id                            username
username                           password
title                              isadmin
image (location)                   points
description                        signup_date
points                             email
category                           city
                                   bio
                                   profile_image
```

I need profile_image to be selected so it can be called upon using $row[profile_image], but I also need all of the information from the images table. Hopefully this clarifies things!

Comment: Sounds you need to JOIN read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: update your question and a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a join  based on user_id
eg for select all the columns for the user_id  = 1

```
  select USERS.* , IMAGES.*
  from USERS
  INNER JOIN IMAGES ON USERS.user_id = IMAGES.user_id
  WHERE USERS.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Sorry for long delay, this isn't quite what I need.. Although it did help me try work out something else but to no avail. I need to be able to call $row[profile_image] from the users table but only select the information from images where the id matches. Using your answer didn't seem to do that, unless I'm being silly?

Comment: then as asked  before  .. update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected .. result  ..